# Perform Mongodb aggregation lookup on two different objectid fields in an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have a teams document that looks something like this:

```
_id: ...,
name: ...,
scheduleId: ...
```

and I have a games document that looks something like this:

```
_id: ...,
scheduleId: ...,
homeTeam: {
  teamId: ...
},
awayTeam: {
  teamId: ...}
```

I want to perform a mongodb aggregation so that the resulting document after aggregation looks like below:

```
id: (Where this is the teamId of the original input document),
name: (name of the team from the input document),
schedule: [
{
  id: (objectId equivalent to scheduleId's referenced in team and games documents.
  homeTeam: {
    id: (objectId of home team),
    name: (name of home team),
    goals: ...,
    assists: ...,
    saves: ...,
    score: ...,
    winner: ...,
  },
  awayTeam: {
    id: (objectId of away team),
    name: (name of home team),
    goals: ...,
    assists: ...,
    saves: ...,
    score: ...,
    winner: ...,
  }
}
```

Here is my existing code (it outputs an array of games with ids for each home team and away team but does not include the name from the corresponding team document. I cannot figure out how to do a lookup on the id's in the nested object to collect each team's name and store it in the corresponding homeTeam/awayTeam object).

```
Team.withUserInfo({
$match: {
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.teamId)
}})

return model.aggregate([
query,
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "captainId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "captain"
  }
},
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$captain"
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "playerIds",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "players"
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "circuits",
    localField: "circuitId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "circuit"
  }
},
{
  $unwind: {
    path: "$circuit"
  }
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "games",
    localField: "scheduleId",
    foreignField: "scheduleId",
    as: "games"
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: false,
    id: "$_id",
    active: true,
    formattedName: true,
    description: true,
    logo: true,
    highestPlayerRank: true,
    circuitId: "$circuit._id",
    scheduleId: true,
    div: true,
    maxPlayers: "$circuit.maxPlayers",
    "captain.id": "$captain._id" ,
    "captain.userName": true,
    players: {
      $map: {
        input: "$players",
        as: "player",
        in: {
          id: "$$player._id" ,
          userName: "$$player.userName"
        }
      }
    },
    schedule: {
      $map: {
        input: "$games",
        as: "game",
        in: {
          id: "$$game._id",
          homeTeam: {
            id: "$$game.homeTeam.teamId",
            goals: "$$game.homeTeam.goals",
            assists: "$$game.homeTeam.assists",
            saves: "$$game.homeTeam.saves",
            score: "$$game.homeTeam.score",
            winner: "$$game.homeTeam.winner",
          },
          awayTeam: {
            id: "$$game.awayTeam.teamId",
            goals: "$$game.awayTeam.goals",
            assists: "$$game.awayTeam.assists",
            saves: "$$game.awayTeam.saves",
            score: "$$game.awayTeam.score",
            winner: "$$game.awayTeam.winner",
          },
          week: "$$game.week",
          date: "$$game.date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

This seems like a relatively simple $lookup somehow but I just can't figure out how to get this done. Any help is greatly appreciated! If something doesn't make sense, please leave a comment and I'll respond.

Comment: What is the issue with the above query? It should work. Or show some more information with posting some sample documents

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet the above query works to pull in data from the game documents, but I need to perform another lookup to the team document so I can pull in the team name. 

I can't seem to figure out how to do a $lookup in the $map function of the query for each homeTeam id and awayTeam id. Does that help?